# Install of SQL Server 2014 SE

Tags: sql-server, installation

The SQL Sever 2014 installation our company has is of SQL Server 2014 SE. I need to install the latest version of SQL Server on there.

I understand that I can install 2014 SE and then apply updates to bring it to SQL Server 2014 SP2 CU7, but I was wondering if there is a way to directly install it to the latest version using the installer?

Answer (score 2):

You could look into slip streaming the installation.

In order to slipstream the updates:

- Download the necessary updates and store them in a location that you have access to (local or UNC path is fine).
- Recent updates are just the .exe file; older CUs were compressed, so if necessary extract the files
- open `cmd`
- change directory to the root of the installation media
- start setup.exe from cmd spcifying the necessary switches

  - `Setup.exe /Action=Install /UpdateEnabled=TRUE /UpdateSource="updates path"`

If this is something that you are likely to do regularly, it is possible to re-package the iso with these updates in.

- Extract ISO image using a utility like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or mount and copy to a directory
- Create an `updates` folder on in the root of the extracted media
- Copy in the required SP/CU
- Recreate the ISO image using any iso image creator such as [MagicISO](http://magiciso.com)

To use the slipstreamed files, open `cmd` and run similar to before:

`Setup.exe /Action=Install /UpdateEnabled=TRUE /UpdateSource=".\updates"`

For a detailed walk through with screenshots see [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/slipstreaming-sql-server-2012-2014/)